# Is it possible to create a discord bot in js that gets the member count of a server from the invite link or the server Id?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So I wanted to make a discord bot in js. If you‘d send the bot an invite link, it should be able to tell you the membercount of the server. Is it possible to program that?

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can do this by having the bot put all the users from the guild into an array once it joins and sending the length of that array.

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const bot = new Discord.Client();
const token = 'YOUR_TOKEN';

bot.on('guildCreate', guild => {
  //first the bot is going to find a channel to send the user count in
  let defaultChannel = "";
  guild.channels.forEach((channel) => {
    if (channel.type == "text" && defaultChannel == "") {
      if (channel.permissionsFor(guild.me).has("SEND_MESSAGES")) {
        defaultChannel = channel;
      }
    }
  })
  let arr = guild.members.array();
  defaultChannel.send(arr.length);

});

bot.login(token);
```